# How to make item template in LazyColumn reusable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can the template I use for my `LazyColumn` items be modfied to enable reuse? What can I use instead of `it` to ensure my `Clothes` sealed interface can be picked up and reused? The code that is a comment is what I was using previously.

```
@Composable
fun ReusableTitleSubtitle() {
    val text1 = when (it) {
        is Clothes.FixedSizeClothing -> stringResource(id = it.itemName)
        is Clothes.MultiSizeClothing -> stringResource(id = it.itemName)
    }

    val text2 = when (it) {
        is Clothes.FixedSizeClothing ->
            stringResource(
                id = R.string.size_placeholder,
                it.itemPlaceholder
            )
        is Clothes.MultiSizeClothing ->
            stringResource(
                id = R.string.sizes_placeholder_and_placeholder,
                it.itemPlaceholders[0], it.itemPlaceholders[1]
            )
    }

    Column() {
        Text(text = text1)
        Text(text = text2)
    }
}
    
sealed interface Clothes {
val itemName: Int

data class FixedSizeClothing(override val itemName: Int, val itemPlaceholder: Int): Clothes
data class MultiSizeClothing(override val itemName: Int, val itemPlaceholders: List<Int>): Clothes
}

@Composable
fun MyScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues()
) {
    Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val clothesItems = remember {
            arrayOf(
                Clothes.FixedSizeClothing(itemName = R.string.chine, itemPlaceholder = 3),
                Clothes.MultiSizeClothing(itemName = R.string.paisley, itemPlaceholders = listOf(1, 2)),
                Clothes.FixedSizeClothing(itemName = R.string.stripy, itemPlaceholder = 7),
                Clothes.FixedSizeClothing(itemName = R.string.tartan, itemPlaceholder = 5),
                Clothes.FixedSizeClothing(itemName = R.string.tattersall, itemPlaceholder = 8)
            )
        }

        MyLazyColumn(
            lazyItems = clothesItems,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(contentPadding)
        ) {
            ReusableTitleSubtitle()
            // val text1 = when (it) {
            //     is Clothes.FixedSizeClothing -> stringResource(id = it.itemName)
            //     is Clothes.MultiSizeClothing -> stringResource(id = it.itemName)
            // }

            // val text2 = when (it) {
            //     is Clothes.FixedSizeClothing ->
            //         stringResource(
            //             id = R.string.size_placeholder,
            //             it.itemPlaceholder
            //         )
            //     is Clothes.MultiSizeClothing ->
            //         stringResource(
            //             id = R.string.sizes_placeholder_and_placeholder,
            //             it.itemPlaceholders[0], it.itemPlaceholders[1]
            //         )
            // }

            // Column() {
            //     Text(text = text1)
            //     Text(text = text2)
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass as parameter `Clothes`:

```
@Composable
fun ReusableTitleSubtitle(clothes:Clothes) {

    val text1 = when (clothes) {
        is Clothes.FixedSizeClothing ->  //...
        is Clothes.MultiSizeClothing ->  //...
    }

    //...
}

@Composable
fun MyLazyColumn(
    lazyItems :  Array<Clothes>,
    modifier : Modifier = Modifier
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        items(lazyItems) {
            ReusableTitleSubtitle(it)
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
    MyLazyColumn(
        lazyItems = clothesItems,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(contentPadding)
    )
```